# Invalid assignment left hand side

Tags: javascript, colors, field, variable-assignment

I'm getting an invalid assignment left hand side.

What I'm trying to do is, to use jscolor http://jscolor.com to define the color of polygons im drawing via Mapbender http://mapbender.org.

What I do: Select a polygon by clicking on it, then open the options dialog (seperate window) where I have several options including the color.

MyCode:

```
        if (isTransactional) {str += "\t\t<tr>\n";
        var options = ["insert", "update", "delete", "abort", "pick"];
        for (var i = 0 ; i < options.length ; i++) {
            var onClickText = "this.disabled=true;var result = window.opener.formCorrect(document, '"+featureTypeElementFormId+"');";
            onClickText +=  "if (result.isCorrect) {";
            onClickText +=      "window.opener.dbGeom('"+options[i]+"', "+memberIndex+"); ";
//              onClickText +=      "window.close();";
                onClickText +=  "}";
            onClickText +=  "else {";
            onClickText +=      "alert(result.errorMessage);this.disabled=false;"
            onClickText +=  "}";
if (options[i] == "insert" && hasGeometryColumn && (!fid || showSaveButtonForExistingGeometries)) {
                str += "\t\t\t<td><input type='button' name='saveButton' value='"+msgObj.buttonLabelSaveGeometry+"' onclick=\""+onClickText+"\" /></td>\n";
            }
if (!featureTypeMismatch && fid) {
                if (options[i] == "update" && hasGeometryColumn) {
                    str += "\t\t\t<td><input type='button' name='updateButton' value='"+msgObj.buttonLabelUpdateGeometry+"' onclick=\""+onClickText+"\"/></td>\n";
                }
if (options[i] == "delete"){ 
                    var deleteOnClickText = "var deltrans = confirm('"+msgObj.messageConfirmDeleteGeomFromDb+"');";
                    deleteOnClickText += "if (deltrans){";
                    deleteOnClickText += onClickText + "}";
                    str += "\t\t\t<td><input type='button' name='deleteButton' value='"+msgObj.buttonLabelDeleteGeometry+"' onclick=\""+deleteOnClickText+"\"/></td>\n";
                }}
if (options[i] == "abort") {
                str += "\t\t\t<td><input type='button' name='abortButton' value='"+msgObj.buttonLabelAbort+"' onclick=\"window.close();\" /></td>\n";
            }
if (options[i] == "pick") {
                var color;
                str += "<td><input class='color' name='color' id='cPick' onchange="+color+"></td>";
                str += "<td><input type='text' id='text' value="+color+"></td>";
                //color = document.getElementById('cPick').value;
                //var color2 = color;
                //alert(color2);
            }
        }str += "\t\t</tr>\n";}str += "\t</table>\n";str += "<input type='hidden' id='fid' value='"+fid+"'>";
//str += "<input type='text' name='mb_wfs_conf'>";


    str += "</form>\n";}return str;}
```

The Application:

It is a Mapbender application to display maps and draw on it. You can draw points, lines and polygons also merge and split them.
You can also select the polygons that you have drawn to alter them.

Using:
PHP, JavaScript, HTML, CSS, Mapbender, jQuery, Geoserver, PostgreSQL, WMS, WFS-T

Comment: What do you want to achieve with `color = document.getElementById('cPick').value;`? What should that make the value of the `onchange` attribute?

Comment: I want to get the value the "color" field returns.

Comment: There isn't a `color` field in your snippet. Don't forget that all anyone has to go on is what you supply. If we need context, provide context. A link to your page is best; more code might suffice.

Comment: What im trying to do is to assign a color to polygons. I select a polygon, open its options, see the fields above and want to change the color of the polygon via jscolor.

Comment: Sorry, can't provide a link because it runs on a test server. Would a printscreen help?

Answer (score 2):

i'm pretty sure it is because of that;

```
 str += "<td><input class='color' name='color' id='cPick' onchange=" + color = document.getElementById('cPick').value; + "></td>";
```

just do

```
var color = document.getElementById('cPick').value; 

 str += "<td><input class='color' name='color' id='cPick' onchange=" + color + "></td>";
```

edit : dont know what you are trying to do since color is not a function , but it should stop displaying the error your get.

Comment: Yeah,but now a new error came up saying document.getElementById('cPick') is null, but the default value of the field is #FFFFFF (white).

Comment: create a fiddle then put your code there ( http://jsfiddle.net ) so people can understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: PHP is needed to run this code correctly, also this is only the code of a single iframe.

Comment: we dont need php code , it has nothing to do with php , since it is client side. if you are pulling datas from the server , just create fake datas so the client code cant work without serverside scripts.

Comment: Maybe a summary will help, it is the code (2500 lines) of a single iframe there are conf files needed (300 Lines), there are 4 .js scripts included, only one css. So even if I create the fake data it will not work because I can't use Mapbender framework.

Answer (score 1):

```
str += "<td><input class='color' name='color' id='cPick' onchange=" + 
    color = document.getElementById('cPick').value; + "></td>";
                                                  ^
                         Syntax error here -------+
```

You should either use a local variable or enclose the `color = ...` statement with parentheses. This fixes the syntactic error, but it won't give you a valid `onchange` handler.